# Eclipse RAP/RWT not containing a Transform class

Tags: eclipse, transformation, eclipse-rap, single-source

I am using Eclipse RWT to port applications written using Eclipse SWT to the web. But unfortunately there is no equivalent class for transformations under org.eclipse.swt.graphics.
You can compare the [Eclipse Platform API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/package-summary.html) and the corresponding [RAP/RWT API](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.rap.doc/guide/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/package-summary.html) to see what else is missing. Concerning **single sourcing** the transformation operations are quite important and yet I couldn’t figure out why these are missing. And before opening a feature request ticket it is probably better to ask if someone already has a solution to this problem.

Comment: As ralfstx and Ivan suggested I have opened an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421842).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the GC API in is not completely implemented in RAP is that some features are hard or impossible to implement in all browsers. For example, in IE7 and IE8, the webclient has to resort to VML to draw, which is very limited. But also the HTML5 Canvas API does not cover all features of the GC API. I guess that transformations are only possible with SVG, which has already been considered as an alternative to HTML Canvas.

I'd suggest that you open an [enhancement request](http://eclipse.org/rap/bugs/) for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. You probably already know this [post](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris/issues/210). Firefox and Chrome were doing well but IE just fires error messages this was the moment I decided not to try IE in this case study again.

Comment: From your answer the question could be raised if it wasn't better to ignore VML to strengthen the use of other _standardized_ technologies in the future and to improve developer experience in the sense of having only one standard everyone knows and everyone uses.

Comment: @dkeck Ignoring VML means to ignore IE8, which still has ~ 8% market share. There are still enough poor devils out there who have to live with that crap.

Comment: +1 for a comment that makes me laugh whenever I open IE. You might like [this](http://www.buzzfeed.com/lukelewis/28-things-only-developers-will-find-funny). Have a look at 7. "This Game"

Answer (score 0):

Please open an enhancement request here [1]. I'm not sure if all the Transform API could be implemented against HTML canvas in all supported by RAP browsers.

[1] http://eclipse.org/rap/bugs/